# Oracle to PostgreSQL database reduces

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Why does the database size reduce in PostgreSQL post migration from Oracle schema having lob, clob and blob datatypes

Comment: Why is it under java tag?

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that Postgres by default compresses values that are bigger than (approximately) 2000 bytes of data variable length data types - these are mainly `text`, `varchar` and `bytea` types.

Oracle will only compress the content of LOB columns if you are using the Enterprise Edition and enable the compression when defining the LOB column (the most important part is to use `SecureFile` instead of `BasicFile`).

Most probably your LOB columns where defined without using compression in Oracle and contain many values bigger than 2000 bytes, that's why you see a reduction in size due to Postgres' automatic compression.